# Подсветка при наведении css

Tags: css, hover

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Доброго дня, господа . Хочу как - то так

[image]

Если без детей, получается, с детьми весь hover назначается всем детям. Помогите . Если что не так написал, уточню . Спасибо

Comment: А как вообще у вас hover прописан то ? Я не вижу.

Comment: .widget.widget_categories /*ul li>ul*/ li>li:hover{
     color: #ea416e;    /*Подсветка категорий*/
}
.widget_categories.children li:hover{
    color: #ea416e;
}

Comment: 1. вся необходимая информация должна быть в вопросе. 2. *лички* здесь нет. если Вы хотите что бы Вам помогли приведите вопрос в соответствии с [рекомендациями](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), первая картинка не нужна, вместо нее лучше приведите разметку и текстом опишите желаемое поведение